# Unit vector orthogonal to the derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm studying some notes of differential geometry and stuck at this point, I'm sure that is easy, maybe I forgot something basic:

> $\forall s\in I$, $|\alpha'(s)|=1$, so $ \langle \alpha'(s),\alpha'(s)\rangle =1$ and $ \langle \alpha'(s),\alpha''(s)\rangle =0$ .

I could not imagine from what I get the second implication.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: 
$$(v \cdot v)'=v' \cdot v + v \cdot v'$$

Comment: Great, many thanks